# Invalid arguments for console cron route in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, console, cron, zend-framework2

I'm trying to make a cron app in my zf2 project but it gave me always the following message :

**Reason for failure: Invalid arguments or no arguments provided**

My code is this:

*module.config.php*

```
'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Sync\Controller\Cron' => 'Sync\Controller\CronController',
            'Sync\Controller\Index' => 'Sync\Controller\IndexController'
        ),
    ),
'console' => array(
        'router' => array(
            'routes' => array(
                'user-reset-password' => array(
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => 'user resetpassword [--verbose|-v] <userEmail>',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'Sync\Controller\Index',
                            'action' => 'password'
                        )
                    )
                ),
                'cron' => array(
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => 'cron [full|center]',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'Sync\Controller\Cron',
                            'action' => 'full'
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

*CronController.php*

```
class CronController extends AbstractActionController
```

{

```
public function fullAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if (!$request instanceof ConsoleRequest) {
        throw new \RuntimeException('You can only use this action from a console!');
    }
    return("hi");
}

public function centerAction()
{

}
```

}

Comment: how does your console command look like? are you calling it with console full?

Comment: My command is : ./bin/guido cron

Comment: you have to call it trough the index.php in your zf2 public folder. It should go something like this: "/whatever/www/zf2/public/index.php cron full"

Comment: If I do this command, the result it's the same

Comment: You shouldn't `return` the string "hi". You should instead `print` or `echo` it, to see a result.

Answer (score 0):

Given that a matching `php` binary is in the path you can then call from your application folder:

`php public/index.php cron full`

or just

`php public/index.php cron` (since the route defaults to the fullAction)